# Is it possible to add an ArcGIS attachment to a row in Oracle using oracle stored procedures?

Tags: python, oracle-spatial, plsql, stored-procedure

So far I have been able to attach files to features within a featureclass using the python tools and ArcObjects.

Within Oracle I have been able to add features with geometries using the ST_Geometry functions from SQL Spatial however, I am wondering if there is a way to add attachments to these features within a stored procedure on the database as opposed to using python or ArcObjects

Comment: Your question is pure oracle (PLSQL) question. Feature attachment has no relevance to spatial data types.